# How to activate and deactivate accounts of users using Node js, MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I want to activate the accounts of users and deactivate them, in the table (user) in the database there are status (boolean) if it is false the account is not active, vice versa, I use the toggle switch to do that, and I write all the code. When the account is active and I click the switch, the status changed in the database to false, but the switch doesn't change (still checked until I refresh the page).
And when the account is not active and I click the switch, the status doesn't change to true in the database.
This is my code, please what the wrong!

```
export const StudentsAccountsTable = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [Status, setStatus] = useState(false);
  const [SSN, setSSN] = useState(0);


  function onToggle(x, y) {
    setStatus(!x);
    setSSN(y);
    Axios.put(`http://localhost:3003/updateStatus`, {
      Status: Status,
      SSN: SSN,
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("success")
    })
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios
      .get("http://localhost:3003/student")
      .then(result => setData(result.data));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table" >
        <thead className="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">الاسم</th>
            <th scope="col">الإيميل</th>
            <th scope="col">الهاتف</th>
            <th scope="col">العنوان</th>
            <th scope="col">تفعيل/إلغاء التفعيل</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item, id) => {
            return <tr key={id}>
              <td>{item.UserName}</td>
              <td>{item.Email}</td>
              <td>{item.Phone}</td>
              <td>{item.Address}</td>
              <td><label className="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked={item.Status} onChange={() => onToggle(item.Status, item.SSN)} />
                <span className="slider round"></span>
              </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And this is in the server:

```
app.put("/updateStatus", (req, res) => {
  const Status= req.body.Status;
  const SSN= req.body.SSN;
  console.log(Status)
  console.log(SSN)
  db.query(`UPDATE user SET Status="${Status}" WHERE user.SSN="${SSN}"`, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.send("Values updated");
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, use parameterized queries and not string substitution for queries, especially with untrusted inputs. This is trivially exploitable via SQL injection.

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain please! 

Comment: Don't build any queries where you're assembling the strings. Especially using input from the user/from the request.  SQL Injection is too big a topic here, but your library probably supports parameterized queries, and use those instead.  https://www.veracode.com/blog/secure-development/how-prevent-sql-injection-nodejs

Comment: Thank you very much, the status now get changed. ^_^
But if you now why the switch doesn't changed, it remains checked for example until I refresh the page.